# How to print a line that is followed by a specific string in a repetitive file?

Tags: command-line, text-processing

This is my first question and I hope you can help me. I've search how to do this but haven't found a solution.

I have a text file with thousand of repetitions like this one:

```
Query= AX-1  
[some lines without pattern]                                                             
A1
B2
C3
R7                                        

Query= AX-2 
[some lines without pattern]                                                                                                     
A1
F5  

Query= AX-3
[some lines without pattern]                                                                                                      
S9
T4
F5
```

I need to print all the Query s that contain a specific string.
For example, if I look for **F5** I should get:

```
AX-2
AX-3
```

and looking for **A1** should print:

```
AX-1
AX-2
```

I think it could be done with a conditional search that print the first previous line starting with "Query". But any way to get this done would be awesome.

Comment: Hi Nicolas, added extended version. Will go to sleep now, but if there is anything, please mention :)

Comment: Hi Jacob. thank you, you are awesome. I cant think of anything else. I will improve y python skills to be able to do stuff like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a small `python` script:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
s = sys.argv[1]; f = sys.argv[2]

currqu = ""
with open(f) as src:
    for l in src:
        if l.startswith("Query"):
            currqu = l.split()[-1].strip()
        if l.strip() == s:
            print(currqu)
```

#### To use

1. Copy the script into an empty file, save it as `quer.py`
2. run it with the string (e.g. F5) and the textfile as arguments:

   ```
   python3 /path/to/quer.py F5 /path/to/file.txt
   ```

If the path contains spaces, use quotes around it.
Since it reads per line, it should be pretty fast on large (huge) files.

#### How it works

- it reads through the lines, looking for a line, starting with `Query`
- if so, it keeps the value in the line "in mind", until the next occurrence of "Query"
- in between it looks for your sought string, prints the value of "Query" if it occurs, *effectively* looking "backwards" if so.

---

### EDIT

As requested in a comment, a version that looks for

- *multiple matches* in one command.

and the script

- *eliminates duplicates*.

It creates an output like:

```
$ '/home/jacob/Bureaublad/pscript_3.py' '/home/jacob/Bureaublad/look.txt' A1 F5
[A1]
AX-1
AX-2
[F5]
AX-2
AX-3
```

#### The script

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
strs = sys.argv[2:]; f = sys.argv[1]

for s in strs:
    print("["+s+"]")
    output = []; currqu = ""
    with open(f) as src:
        for l in src:
            if l.startswith("Query"):
                currqu = l.split()[-1].strip()
            if l.strip() == s:
                output.append(currqu)
        for item in sorted(set(output)):
            print(item)
```

#### How to use

*Almost* the same as the first script, but now, *start* with the file as argument, then the strings. In principle, you can have as many strings as you like in one command.

```
python3 /path/to/quer.py /path/to/file.txt F5 A1 B6 C7
```

etc, etc.

Comment: Hi @NicolasSalcedo thanks for mentioning. Always makes me happy :)

Comment: Do you have any suggestion on how to search various strings at the same time? I can only do this with one at a time.

Comment: @NicolasSalcedo sure, but I gues s it would need to be grouped per sought string? And (silly question) from one textfile?

Comment: Not really, the idea is to merge all in single list.  Either, I can concatenate the resulting lists and delete the duplicates.

Comment: To merge all lists (files) into one would be the best idea. The script should not have problems with huge files; it doesn't load the whole file. Dupes can be easily eliminated by `set(list)`

Comment: Yes it is the same file. So, in my example, if I wanted to look for F5 then A1 how would be the syntax. I've tried:
python3 /path/to/quer.py F5;A1 /path/to/file.txt

Comment: @NicolasSalcedo I'll post an edited version...

Answer (score 1):

This awk command could do the job:

```
awk -v RS='\n\n' -v target=<string> '$0 ~ target {print $2}'
```

For example:

```
$ awk -v RS='\n\n' -v target=F5 '$0 ~ target {print $2}' foo.txt 
AX-2
AX-3
$ awk -v RS='\n\n' -v target=A1 '$0 ~ target {print $2}' foo.txt
AX-1
AX-2
```

I'm assuming that:

1. the Query sections are all separated by blank lines (hence, two newlines `\n\n` as the record separator),
2. there's a space after the `Query=`, so that the string you want to print is the second field (`$2`),
3. the string you want to search for doesn't have regex special characters 
   like `.` or `*`. If so, another function might have to be used.